# How to prove that a manifold with Self-Dual Riemann tensor is Ricci-flat

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

By self-dual I mean that \begin{equation} *\mathcal{R}_{ab}=\mathcal{R}_{ab}\,, \end{equation}
where $\mathcal{R}$ is the curvature 2-form, related to the Riemann tensor $R$ by $\mathcal{R}_{ab}= (1/2) R_{abcd} \,\,e^c\wedge e^d$.

By Ricci flat I mean that the Ricci tensor, which can be obtained as the 1-3 contraction of the Riemann tensor, vanishes.

I know how to prove the statement in the title by explicit computation, using the symmetry properties of the Riemann tensor $R_{abcd}= - R_{bacd}$, $R_{abcd} = -R_{ab dc}$, $R_{abcd}=R_{cdab}$ , and the algebraic Bianchi identity $R_{a[bcd]}=0$.

> I would like to see a "computation free" proof of the statement in the title.

Comment: The orthogonal group acts on the vector space of 4-tensors with the symmetries of a curvature tensor. It can be decomposed into irreducible representations of the orthogonal group. The subspace of self dual curvature tensors and the subspace of Ricci flat curvature tensors are themselves invariant under the action of the orthogonal group. There should be a way using representation theory to show the former subspace is contained in the latter. One possible way is to decompose each into irreducible representations.

Answer (score 1):

I found a 'computational free' way by reading this article by [ST68](http://www.google.com.hk/url?q=https://www.intlpress.com/site/pub/files/_fulltext/journals/sdg/2001/0006/0001/SDG-2001-0006-0001-a010.pdf&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwi17rHj98GEAxWz8LsIHdVLDyIQFnoECAkQAg&usg=AOvVaw3GZ8zgfXM4z_rkSC3crSkU).

The method use Thm1.3 of this article,i.e.,we need to show
\begin{equation} *R\in\mathcal{R}_3\,, \end{equation}
where $R$ denote the curvature form.

We can show the self dual condition for curvature form equivalent to same equation of curvature operator,i.e.
the composition of Hodge star and curvature operator equal to curvature operator.Then by symmetry we deduce

\begin{equation}
*R=R=R*\,, 
\end{equation}
here $R$ for  curvature operator.

and then

\begin{equation}
*R=R*\,\\
s=tr(R)=0\,, 
\end{equation}

the first equivalent to say the 4-manifold is Einstein.

to obtain the latter we need decompose to self and anti-self dual part of the space of two forms,and the trace of right-down part is, which equal to half of scalar curvature, zero